# Can a node act as a server and a publisher?

Tags: ros, service, server, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I have a piece of hardware (LabJack UE9) I am using to interface with a diesel generator for data acquisition as well as for some simple controls (turning it on and off), and I would like to have the node that interfaces with it to be capable of both publishing acquired data and servicing client requests to turn the generator on and off. Is this possible? I have successfully implemented client/servers as well as publishers/subscribers, but I am having problems stitching them together.

Thanks

Gideon

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10905/can-a-node-act-as-a-server-and-a-publisher?/) by [Gideon](https://answers.ros.org/users/362/gideon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 239 on 2011-08-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes it can, although I am still uncertain what happens to the published messages when the service takes a while to fulfill the request. For anyone else trying to do this, I found the stitching together of examples from the tutorials much easier once I found class based examples (http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/UsingClassMethodsAsCallbacks)

---

Originally posted by [Gideon](https://answers.ros.org/users/362/gideon/) with karma: 239 on 2011-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-08-15**:
Once the message has been "published" the service call will not effect it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have written a set of [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/Publisher%20and%20Subscriber%20with%20Parameters%20and%20Dynamic%20Reconfigure) that should help clear up how to have a publisher/subscriber along with a dynamic reconfigure server running within a single node. The nodes also use classes for the majority of the work/callback functions which I have found to be the cleanest way to do things with pub/sub in general. It should not be too difficult to stitch in a server/client to the example provided in the tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2011-08-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2